# CheckBoxes in GridVIew does not remain selected when paginating through the GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I'm trying to work through some examples to understand how to make `CheckBoxes` remain selected when paginating through `GridView`.

I'm trying to replicate an example of paging through the `GridView`. I'm using the following example:

http://aspalliance.com/774_Maintaining_State_of_CheckBoxes_While_Paging_in_a_GridView_Control.all

The only difference is that I use my own GridView as following:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridViewExample._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" DataKeyNames="Key" PageSize="4" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gvCustomersPageChanging" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

    <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Checked="false" Value='<%#Eval("Key") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Key">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Key") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("LastName") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

This is the data loading logic:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{
    var customers = new List<Customer>{
        new Customer { FirstName = "Mohammad",  LastName = "Azam", Key = 1},
        new Customer { FirstName = "John",  LastName = "Doe",  Key = 2},
        new Customer { FirstName = "Mary",  LastName = "Kate",  Key = 3},
        new Customer { FirstName = "Jerry",  LastName = "Seinfeld",  Key = 4},
        new Customer { FirstName = "Alex",  LastName = "Rowe",  Key = 5},
        new Customer { FirstName = "James",  LastName = "Smith",  Key = 9},
        new Customer { FirstName = "Jerry",  LastName = "Grand",  Key = 10},
        new Customer { FirstName = "Thomas",  LastName = "Anders",  Key = 11},
        new Customer { FirstName = "Diter",  LastName = "Bolen",  Key = 12},
        new Customer { FirstName = "Ryan",  LastName = "McDonag",  Key = 13},
        new Customer { FirstName = "Stewart",  LastName = "Black",  Key = 14},
        new Customer { FirstName = "James",  LastName = "Soth",  Key = 15},
        new Customer { FirstName = "Alex",  LastName = "Bowldwin",  Key = 18},
        new Customer { FirstName = "Arnold",  LastName = "Strong",  Key = 19},
    };


    gvCustomers.DataSource = (from c in customers select c).ToList();

    gvCustomers.DataBind();
}
```

This is the code from the example:

```
   private void RememberOldValues()
    {
        ArrayList categoryIDList = new ArrayList();
        int index = -1;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCustomers.Rows)
        {
            index = (int)gvCustomers.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
            bool result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked;
            string id = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).ClientID;

            // Check in the Session
            if (Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] != null)
                categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
            if (result)
            {
                if (!categoryIDList.Contains(index))
                    categoryIDList.Add(index);
            }
            else
                categoryIDList.Remove(index);
        }
        if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
            Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] = categoryIDList;
    }

    private void RePopulateValues()
    {
        ArrayList categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
        if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCustomers.Rows)
            {
                int index = (int)gvCustomers.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
                if (categoryIDList.Contains(index))
                {
                    CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
                    myCheckBox.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

protected void gvCustomersPageChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  RememberOldValues();
  gvCustomers.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  BindData();
  RePopulateValues();
}
```

The problem is even though I select the checkbox, when debugging the following line:

```
bool result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked;
```

in `RememberOldValues()` method, `result` is always false

Why is that? Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly in your page's code-behind are these methods being called  - `RememberOldValues` and `RePopulateValues`?

Comment: I call them in `gvCustomers_PageIndexChanging` method. `RememberOldValues` is called before changing `PageIndex` and `RePopulateValues` is called after binding to `GridView`

Comment: Can you put that event code as well in your post? Its best to look at maximum code to provide a quick solution.

Comment: I put that method at the end of the post

Comment: Can you try removing the `Checked=false` from your markup for check box and then see if it still gives a false value?

Comment: @Sunil, I removed as you suggested. All the same

Comment: I tried the exact same code as yours except a different data source and it works perfectly. Look at this video: http://screencast.com/t/oAd8sl4QRF

Comment: Can you set the following two properties in GridView: EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"? Also, do you get a non-zero count for gvCustomers.Rows.Count?

Comment: Let me also try using your exact data dource. Give me 10 minutes.

Comment: I think I know your problem. Please try this NOW. In your Page_Load event bind data only if its not a post back.  Try it as I write the answer for you.

Comment: Read my answer since its a one-second fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Page_Load event, please replace the code with the one below.

Every time you page through the gridview, the page posts back and you rebind it before the `PageIndexChanging` event is reached because you always bind the gridview in `Page_Load` event, which resets the checkboxes to their default false value. With code below, it will never re-bind before the event of `PageIndexChanging` is reached and your checkbox values will be preserved.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
       BindData();
     }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, sometimes its just a small part that is being overlooked. But use this as a thumb rule in ASP.Net that only bind in `Page_Load` if its not a post back.